# Formula Parse Error in Google Spreadsheet Sparkline

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having some trouble using the SPARKLINE function on Google Spreasheets. If I use the "default" formula, like `=SPARKLINE(C9:N9)`, it works nicelly. But, everytime I try to add some extra options, like using columns instead of lines, for example `=SPARKLINE(C11:N11;{"charttype", "bar"})`, I get a "Error, Formula parse error." message.

Has anyone here had the same problem? Any idea of how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Google sheets now seems to autocorrect the semi-colon argument-separator to a comma: `=SPARKLINE(C11:N11, {"charttype", "bar"})`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/QzVhyW5bi-A

> When you address the option like an object, then you should use a backslash: `=SPARKLINE(C11:N11;{"charttype"\"bar"}`

Comment: That's great!!!! Thanks a lot @Eddie!, just a detail, I had to remove the parentesis, so the final code was =SPARKLINE(C11:N11;{"charttype"\"bar"})

Comment: Yeah, the "sample usage" section is totally wrong (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289)